# Parsing Alexa for rank info

Tags: regex, python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

From Alexa, I want to extract the integer associated with `<REACH RANK="1"/>`. What I mean:

```xml
<!--
    Need more Alexa data?  Find our APIS here: https://aws.amazon.com/alexa/
-->
<ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="google.com/" HOME="0" AID="=" IDN="google.com/">
  <SD TITLE="A" FLAGS="" HOST="google.com">
    <OWNER NAME="aa"/>
  </SD>
  <SD>
    <POPULARITY URL="google.com/" TEXT="1" SOURCE="panel"/>
    <REACH RANK="1"/>
    <RANK DELTA="+0"/> 
    <COUNTRY CODE="US" NAME="United States" RANK="1"/>
  </SD>
</ALEXA>
```

What I have tried so far are recommendations from this [Github](https://gist.github.com/masnun/3170870) post and messing with regex patterns found on [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) while trying different variations of code with said regex patterns.

What I have currently:

```
 try:
    xml = (BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=" + url).read(), "xml"))

    rank = re.search(r'"<REACH[^>]*RANK="(\d+")', xml)
    print(rank)
    print(f'Your rank for {url} is {rank}')
 except Exception as err:
    print(err)
    rank = -1
    #print(f'Your rank for {url} is {rank}')
```

It either 1) Hits the exception or 2) Results in this error:

`expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse structured formats. This is XML; use an XML parser. BeautifulSoup contains useful code for extracting XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using BeautifulSoup, you can parse it with `xml`. Something like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

endpoint = 'http://data.alexa.com/data'

url = 'insert the value you are using here'

data = dict(
    cli=10,
    dat=snbamz,
    url=url
)

r = requests.get(url, data=data)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'xml')

rank = soup.REACH.get('RANK')
```

It is not a complete example but I hope it can be used as a starting point where you can develop from there.

Here is a proof of concept:

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Dec 15 2019, 17:54:26) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> alexa = '''
... <!--
...     Need more Alexa data?  Find our APIS here: https://aws.amazon.com/alexa/
... -->
... <ALEXA VER="0.9" URL="google.com/" HOME="0" AID="=" IDN="google.com/">
...   <SD TITLE="A" FLAGS="" HOST="google.com">
...     <OWNER NAME="aa"/>
...   </SD>
...   <SD>
...     <POPULARITY URL="google.com/" TEXT="1" SOURCE="panel"/>
...     <REACH RANK="1"/>
...     <RANK DELTA="+0"/> 
...     <COUNTRY CODE="US" NAME="United States" RANK="1"/>
...   </SD>
... </ALEXA>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(alexa, 'xml')
>>> rank = soup.REACH.get('RANK')
>>> rank
'1'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks this does what I was intending to accomplish. Another question I have that is somewhat on topic is if I am using BS within the same Python document to parse different websites although all declared `soups` are within different `try` blocks, can I keep re-declaring `soup` in the same Python file while keeping soups integrity if I am making sense? So, `try: soup = ... except: ...` 15 lines of code later: `try: soup = ... except: ...`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are going to overwrite `soup` on every call. If you need to keep all of them, just use a list instead. Something like this `soups = []` and then, on every block, `soups.add(BeautifulSoup(next_xml, 'xml'))`. I guess you got the idea.